# Button onclick, executing JS funtion then GS code

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, onclick

Sorry for English mistakes but I'm not english.

Starting from this example [Form to upload files with sending email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29336634/form-to-upload-files-with-sending-email-address) long time ago I've changed the button code from:

```
  <input type="button" value="Submit"
      onclick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateUrl)
          .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
          .uploadFiles(this.parentNode)" />
```

to:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit"
      onclick="test()" />
```

the complete HTML page was:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Your full name..."/>
  <input name="myFile" type="file" />
  <input type="button" value="Submit"
      onclick="test()" />
</form>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
    function test(){
    console.log ("I'm running");
    
    google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateUrl)
          .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
          .uploadFiles(this.parentNode)
          
    }

    function updateUrl(url) {
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        div.innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '">Got it!</a>';
    }
    function onFailure(error) {
        alert(error.message);
    }
</script>

<style>
  input { display:block; margin: 20px; }
</style>
```

It worked for 1 year, few days ago it stopped.
If I open the console I see the "I'm running message" correctly but nothing happens in the spreadsheet or in the folder.

Can someone tell me why?
I nedd to run some JS code before executing GS code, it worked but not now, what is changed?

Thanks.

Comment: When you moved the `google.script.run.myFunction()` code from the button to the `<script>` tag, the `this` keyword refers to something different.  So, `this.parentNode` is no longer referring to the form element when the `google.script.run.myFunction()` code is in the `<script>` tag.  You'll need to get the form element with `var theForm = document.getElementById("myForm");` and then use `google.script.run.myFunction(theForm)`.  If this works, I'll post as an answer.

Comment: In this example your solutions works!! Thanks! Now I try to fix my real script and I will let you know if it works!

Comment: @SandyGood it works, Thanks! Can you tell me why the previous code worked for a long time? Is something changed? Is something going to change?

Comment: The context of your onclick script changed.

Comment: I doesn't make any sense to me that the code you have provided as the original would have worked.  Unexplained things happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you moved the `google.script.run.myFunction()` code from the button to the `<script>` tag, it causes the `this` keyword to refer to something different. So, `this.parentNode` is no longer referring to the form element with the `google.script.run.myFunction()` code in the `<script>` tag. You'll need to get the form element with

```
var theForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
```

and then use:

```
google.script.run.myFunction(theForm).
```

OR:

instead of using `var theForm = document.getElementById("myForm");`

You can pass the form element with:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="test(this.parentNode)" />
```

And:

```
function test(theForm){
```